# How do I read a button through the GPIO?

Tags: gpio, python

I considered myself out of this sort of beginner level stuff a long time ago, but I guess I'm not as smart as I thought I was because I seem to be having an exceptional level of trouble with it!

So I've finally finished exams and can play with my new toy, so the first thing I did was get an LCD character display rigged up over UART. I got that working no problem, so I am having a really hard time figuring out why I am having such a hard time with this button!

So I've set up a button similar to the way one would with an arduino; with a 1k resistor connecting to ground. I used my multimeter to ensure that the button was working and putting out the right amount of power, which it is. I SSH into my shell, plug the button into GPIO pin 7 and went into python. Here's what I tried:

```
GPIO.pinout(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
while 1==1:
    inputval = GPIO.input(7)
    print inputval
```

This gives me an endless loop of `False` regardless of how I press the button. I tried it with `GPIO.PUD_UP` as well and got an endless loop of `True` instead.  I also tried it with `GPIO.PUD_OFF` and got more `False`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So you have the switch in series with the 1k resistor to GND? That should work with `GPIO.PUD_UP`. What voltage do you see with `GPIO.PUD_UP` on and the button pressed?

Comment: Slightly confused; what is the switch connected to?

Comment: Hello Michael and welcome to [raspberrypi.se]! I have taken the liberty of merging your two accounts. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

My GPIO doesn't have `pinout`, I had to change it to `setmode`

```
import time
from RPi import GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
while True:
    inputval = GPIO.input(7)
    print inputval
    time.sleep(1)
```

Since you are using `GPIO.BOARD` pin 7 is the one labelled `GPIO 4(GPCLK0)`. If you meant to use `GPIO 7(CE1)`, you should use `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` instead

[image]

I tested the code by touching a 1k resistor from `3V3 Power` to `GPIO 4(GPCLK0)`

Comment: I am almost certain your correct on why it was not working. I was under the impression `GPIO.BOARD` was for the pinout of the board itself as shown in the pictures, not the physical pin numbering scheme. When I get home from work I will try it out and I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I never use "pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN" in the setup of the pin. Try this:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PinNum,GPIO.IN)
while 1==1:
    if GPIO.input(PinNum)==1:
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

As gnibbler said, make sure PinNum is for the BCM GPIO.